# Why doesn't Firefox show any kind of a feed presence indication when there is are RSS/Atom feeds associated with the page?

Tags: firefox, rss, xml, blogging, atom-feed

For example I've came to a webpage having the following tag inside its <head> tag:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="A blog feed" href="http://johndoe.github.com/atom.xml">
```

Or a blogger.com blog having both RSS and Atom feeds rels.

But my Firefox (7.0.1 on XUbuntu 11.10) doesn't indicate this! I have to view a page source code to see whether there is an RSS/Atom feed for it or not. Why? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ongoing and bizarre process of making people less aware of RSS, the RSS icon was removed from version 4 onwards.

There are extensions that restore the icon:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rss-icon/?src=search

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rss-icon-in-awesombar/?src=search

There may be others too...

Comment: Instead of adding a 3rd-party extension, I prefer using the builtin functionality, it is still present on my Firefox 22 (although hidden and disabled by default)

Answer (score 4):

There are still two built-in ways how to recognize/subscribe to feeds in Firefox:

- in "Bookmarks" menu you can subscribe to the current page's feed(s) (if any available)
- you can add a feed icon to the toolbar (by right-clicking at the toolbar), which gets activated as soon as a feed is detected

The latter variant is preferred of course, because it informs you (visually) that a feed is availabe, while the former variant would require you to visit the Bookmarks menu.